# Why 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration here

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, type-traits, enable-if

```
#include<string>
#include<type_traits>

template<typename... Args>
class C {
public:
    void foo(Args&&... args) {      

    }

    template<typename = std::enable_if_t<(0 < sizeof...(Args))>>
    void foo(const Args&... args) {     

    }
};

int main() {
    C<> c;
    c.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Above code works as expacted (by me :)) and calls `void foo(Args&&... args)` at run-time in *msvc 2015* but same code fails to even compile in both *gcc 7.3* and *clang 6.0.0* with error:

> error: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if';
>   'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration

I want to understand what is wrong with the above code and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Are you familiar with SFINAE? The existing answer isn't bad _per se_, but it doesn't explain SFINAE. Yet I'd think that if you understand SFINAE, the question would be already answered.

Comment: @MSalters: I am familiar with SFINAE, apparently not very well :) but thankfully, enough to understand the answer given here and explore further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SFINAE only works for deduced template arguments. In your case your method did not depend on any parameter from the method call so it is not in a deduced context. Everything is already known while instantiate the class itself.

MSVC is simply wrong in that case.

Workaround:

```
template<typename... Args>
class C
{
    public:
        template< typename U = std::tuple<Args...>>
            std::enable_if_t< (std::tuple_size<U>::value > 0 ) > foo(const Args&...)
            {
                std::cout << "Args  > 0 type " << std::endl;
            }

        template< typename U = std::tuple<Args...>>
            std::enable_if_t< (std::tuple_size<U>::value == 0)> foo(const Args&...)
            {
                std::cout << "Args 0 type " << std::endl;
            }
};

int main()
{
    C<>{}.foo();
    C<int>{}.foo(1);
}
```

I don't know why you need such a overload, because if the parameter list is empty, you simply should write an overload for such without any SFINAE stuff at all.

if your compiler is not outdated ( c++14 only ) it is much easier with using `constexpr if`:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct C
{
    void foo (const Args&... args)
    {
        if constexpr ( sizeof...(args) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "0" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << ">0" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main ()
{
    C<>    c0;
    C<int> c1;
    c0.foo();
    c1.foo(42);
}
```

EDIT after comment:

To avoid SFINAE you can also use specialized template classes like this:

```
// provide common stuff here
template <typename ... ARGS>
class CAll { protected: void DoSomeThing(){ std::cout << "Do some thing" << std::endl; } };

template<typename ... ARGS>
class C;

// special for no args
template<>
class C<>: public CAll<>
{   
    public:
        void foo() 
        {
            std::cout << "none" << std::endl; 
            this->DoSomeThing();
        }   
};  

//special for at minimum one arg
template<typename FIRST, typename ... REST>
class C<FIRST, REST...>: public CAll<FIRST, REST...>
{   
    public:
        void foo( FIRST&, REST&... )
        {   
            std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
            this->DoSomeThing();
        }

        void foo( FIRST&&, REST&&... )
        {   
            std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
            this->DoSomeThing();
        }   
};  

int main()
{   
    int a;
    C<>{}.foo();
    C<int>{}.foo(1);
    C<int>{}.foo(a);
}
```

Comment: Why I need such overload?: If you look at my code above between the two functions first one `void foo(Args&&... args)` will work with rvalue referenses and the second one `void foo(const Args&... args)` with rest. The only time they conflict is when `C` is instantiated with no parameter. Basically, I wanted to achieve something like perfect forwarding with class template arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: _"SFINAE only works for deduced template arguments"_ - is this really true? Afaik SFINAE also works fine applied to explicitly specified template arguments as well as default template arguments, none of which are obtained as deduced template arguments. Rather, which applies also in OP's case, the `enable_if` construct needs to contain _some_ template argument from the entity upon which is applied, otherwise the `enable_if` construct itself will never take part of the template parameter _substitutation_ (where template argument deduction is one part) for that entity, in which case SFINAE fails.

Comment: And indeed, SFINAE does emphasize on _substitutation_ (*S*FINAE) and not deduction (*D*FINAE?).

Answer (score 6):

As better explained by Klaus, your original code doesn't works because `std::enable_if_t` need to check a template of the method itself and isn't enough the template list of the class.

I propose a simplified alternative of the Klaus's solution.

First of all, you need a template parameter to check; you can use one with a default value deduced from the template paramenter of the class (`Args...`).

Surely you can use a type taking a `std::tuple` of the `Args...` but, taking in count that you're only interested in the number of `Args...` parameters, I find it's simpler to use a `std::size_t` template parameter initialized with the number of `Args...`

```
template <std::size_t N = sizeof...(Args)>
std::enable_if_t<N> foo (Args const & ... args)
 { std::cout << "N args" << std::endl; }
```

Regarding the zero args version, there is no need to make it a template version; you can simply write it with zero parameters

```
void foo ()
 { std::cout << "zero args" << std::endl; }
```

In case of zero `Args...`, the not-template version take the precedence over the template one.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Args>
struct C
 {
   void foo ()
    { std::cout << "zero args" << std::endl; }

   template <std::size_t N = sizeof...(Args)>
   std::enable_if_t<N> foo(const Args&... args)
    { std::cout << "N args" << std::endl; }
};

int main ()
 {
   C<>    c0;
   C<int> c1;
   c0.foo();
   c1.foo(42);
 }
```