# std::enable_if cannot be used to disable this declaration

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, inner-classes, sfinae, type-traits

I have a quite complex piece of code which I simplified to this reproducer :

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
template<typename ...As>
struct outer {
    template<typename ...Bs>
    struct inner {
        template<bool dummy, typename E = void>
        struct problem;
        using TA = std::tuple<As...>;
        using TB = std::tuple<Bs...>;

        template<bool dummy>
        struct problem<dummy, typename std::enable_if<std::tuple_size<TA>::value < std::tuple_size<TB>::value>::type>
        {
            static constexpr auto val() { return 1; } // actually a complex function
        };

        template<bool dummy>
        struct problem<dummy, typename std::enable_if<std::tuple_size<TA>::value >= std::tuple_size<TB>::value>::type>
        {
            static constexpr auto val() { return 0; }
        };
    };
};

int main() {
    return outer<int, float>::inner<double>::problem<false>::val();
}
```

it doesn't compile (with gcc or clang), saying :

```
<source>:13:82: error: failed requirement 'std::tuple_size<std::tuple<int, float> >::value < std::tuple_size<std::tuple<double> >::value'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration

        struct problem<dummy, typename std::enable_if<std::tuple_size<TA>::value <std::tuple_size<TB>::value>::type>

                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

<source>:27:31: note: in instantiation of template class 'outer<int, float>::inner<double>' requested here

    return outer<int, float>::inner<double>::problem<false>::val();
```

I tried some variants, and nothing works.

I read some already posted Q&A, such as : 
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713692/why-enable-if-cannot-be-used-to-disable-this-declaration-here)
or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52077051/sfinae-enable-if-cannot-be-used-to-disable-this-declaration)
but they don't seem to answer my question.

PS : I can use C++17, but that must work with any compiler.

Comment: The reason is that the requirement is not a dependent expression in the instantiation of `problem`. In this specific example it's possible to make `val` just return `std::tuple_size<std::tuple<int, float> >::value < std::tuple_size<std::tuple<double> >::value ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: no it's not possible. val is actually a complex function

Comment: You might want to look into "if constexpr" which results in much simpler code then enable_if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: try something as follows

```
struct inner {
    using TA = std::tuple<As...>;
    using TB = std::tuple<Bs...>;

    template<bool dummy, typename UA = TA, typename E = void>
    struct problem;

    template<bool dummy, typename UA>
    struct problem<dummy, UA,
       std::enable_if_t<(std::tuple_size_v<UA> < std::tuple_size_v<TB>)>>
     { static constexpr auto val() { return 1; } };

    template<bool dummy, typename UA>
    struct problem<dummy, UA,
       std::enable_if_t<(std::tuple_size_v<UA> >= std::tuple_size_v<TB>)>>
     { static constexpr auto val() { return 0; } };
};
```

I mean... take in count that SFINAE works with tests over template parameter of the struct/class (or function, or method) that you want enable/disable.

The problem in your original code is that the SFINAE test regards only `TA` and `TB` that are types defined in the `inner` struct that contain `problem`. So the test depends only from external template parameters (`As...` and `Bs...`), not from template arguments of `problem`.

Adding a template argument with default value for `problem`

```
// ..................VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
template<bool dummy, typename UA = TA, typename E = void>
struct problem;
```

doesn't change the practical use of `problem` itself but transform the test in `std::enable_if`

```
template<bool dummy, typename UA>
struct problem<dummy, UA, // ..........VV  UA, not TA
   std::enable_if_t<(std::tuple_size_v<UA> < std::tuple_size_v<TB>)>>
 { static constexpr auto val() { return 1; } };
```

in a test that involve a template parameter of `problem` itself.

Comment: well. Thank you. How to introduce a false dependency.

Comment: @RegisPortalez - see also the other answers (and the important comment from Unimportant): my answer works (with little modifications) from C++11 and (I hope) explain why doesn't works your original code. But, if you can use C++17, `if constexpr` (maybe in this case; surely in others) permit simpler and more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 2):

As @unimportant commented: [if-constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) since C++17. Allows you to get rid of `dummy` and many more lines:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename ...As>
struct outer {
    template<typename ...Bs>
    struct inner {
        using TA = std::tuple<As...>;
        using TB = std::tuple<Bs...>;

        static constexpr auto val() { 
            if constexpr (std::tuple_size_v<TA> >= std::tuple_size_v<TB>) {
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    };
};

int main() {
    return outer<int, float>::inner<double>::val();
}
```

> The program '[4544] main.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, using `if constexpr` (part of C++17) makes the code way simpler:

```
template<typename ...As>
struct outer {
    template<typename ...Bs>
    struct inner {
        using TA = std::tuple<As...>;
        using TB = std::tuple<Bs...>;

        struct problem
        {
            static constexpr auto val()
            {
                if constexpr (std::tuple_size<TA>::value < std::tuple_size<TB>::value)
                    return 1; // Complex function goes here
                else
                    return 0; // Other complex function (?) goes here
            }
        };
    };
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+...As%3E%0Astruct+outer+%7B%0A++++template%3Ctypename+...Bs%3E%0A++++struct+inner+%7B%0A++++++++using+TA+%3D+std::tuple%3CAs...%3E%3B%0A++++++++using+TB+%3D+std::tuple%3CBs...%3E%3B%0A%0A++++++++struct+problem%0A++++++++%7B%0A++++++++++++static+constexpr+auto+val()%0A++++++++++++%7B%0A++++++++++++++++if+constexpr+(std::tuple_size%3CTA%3E::value+%3C+std::tuple_size%3CTB%3E::value)%0A++++++++++++++++++++return+1%3B+//+Complex+function+goes+here%0A++++++++++++++++else%0A++++++++++++++++++++return+0%3B+//+Other+complex+function+(%3F)+goes+here%0A++++++++++++%7D%0A++++++++%7D%3B%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++return+outer%3Cint,+float%3E::inner%3Cdouble%3E::problem::val()%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:45.4295154185022,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang800,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:'334')),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+8.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:48.13037651941832,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+8.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:54.570484581497794,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)